# Paste Image from Microsoft Office to AIR Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm in a situation where I need to accept copied images from a Word (.doc / .docx) document to a spark image on the AIR application. I tried with a sample document with an image embedded inside. When I open it up on Pages on Mac, the copied image pastes perfectly onto the the spark image object via the code below:

```
var clipboardImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT) as BitmapData);
clipboardImage.width = fldPicture.width;
clipboardImage.height = fldPicture.height;
fldPicture.source = clipboardImage;
```

`fldPicture` is the spark image. This may have been okay but when I sent the AIR application and the same Word document over to a friend who runs Windows and has Microsoft Office 2010, it didn't work. It only seems to work if the copied image from the Word document is pasted to MS Paint then copied again but this time, from the MS Paint.

Sorry if this seems rather confusing, I tried to explain it as much as I could. If anyone can shed some light on this issue, it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mmh I'm afraid it has to do with the way Word handles file formats and so. 
Word uses a lot of headers, internal-code / tags only used by itself to recognize objets, text formats, images...
And I suppose the content of the clipboard coming from Word has to be stripped from this headers of some kind before it can be used, thing that Paint automatically do (thing that could explain why it works when getting to Paint before pasting it in your app).
Maybe you could try to put the pasted data into a byte array and try to remove the headers manually before getting it into a Bitmap ?...